# Python try-except multiple values in loop and skip current iteration if any exceptions raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm converting values to float from multiple columns in a dataset concurrently in a loop, where I try to skip bad rows with a ValueError exception

My data has been loaded with a structure that enables me to loop over it as such

```
A_floated = []
B_floated = []

for i in range(len(data)):

    A = data[i]["column_A"]
    B = data[i]["column_B"]

    try:
        A = float(A)
        A_floated.append(A)

        B = float(B)
        B_floated.append(B)

    except(ValueError):
        continue
```

I want the exception to encompass both A and B, so that if *any* of them contains a bad row, all of them will be skipped for this i, so that `len(A_floated) == len(B_floated)`. Right now, I can only figure out how to skip bad rows on an individual-column basis, but then I end up with floated columns of different lengths.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to gather 'good' (floated) rows in data structures `A_floated` and `B_floated` respectively during iteration through `data`. If so, try putting the former data structures outside the loop, and check whether values can be converted into floats *before* putting them into lists. Otherwise, value A may be convertible while value B not, which would result in different lengths of `A_floated` and `B_floated`. To sum it up, try the following code:

```
A_floated = []
B_floated = []

for i in range(len(data)):

    A = data[i]["column_A"]
    B = data[i]["column_B"]

    try:
        # "floatability" check.
        A = float(A)
        B = float(B)

        # If both values can be converted into a float,
        # put them into the respective lists.
        A_floated.append(A)
        B_floated.append(B)

    except(ValueError):
        continue
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put the empty lists outside of the loop while I wrote the example! Sorry for the blunder.

Comment: Also, I didn't know that both of the float checks needed to be called first before appending, and that it would be different from a try block with a potential error *somewhere* inside. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the [`else` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) which runs if no exception occurs. `try` and convert, don't do any appending there and, if no errors occur, you append in the `else` clause:

```
try:
    A = float(A)
    B = float(B)
except ValueError:
    continue
else:
    A_floated.append(A)
    B_floated.append(B)
```

I removed the parentheses around the `ValueError` since they aren't necessary.